# Typescript compilation with copyfiles in NPM scripts

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json, tsconfig

I am trying to convert a code from JS into TS. I repeatedly get:
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3004

I have to change ports and kill ports `sudo fuser -k 3004/tcp` quite often.

My package.json file has following:

```
 "scripts": {
    "copy:templates": "cp -r ./templates ./build/",
    "copy:data": "cp -r ./dev-data ./build/",
    "copy": "npm run copy:templates; npm run  copy:data",
    "build": "tsc -w",
    "runNode": "nodemon build/index.js",
    "start": "npm run copy; npm run build ; npm run runNode"
  }
```

My tsconfig.json has

```
    "outDir": "./build", 
    "rootDir": "./src" ,
```

Finally executing as `npm start`

**I believe there is something wrong with my NPM run scripts**. I am not even running scripts in parallel to avoid this problem. I have also used [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) to replace `cp -r`. However I am not successful so far.

Should I use Gulp? I don't want to, if I don't have to.
 **Is there something obvious that someone can point out?**

Comment: I found one issue here that script ```"build": "tsc -w"``` should not be run sequentially. ```tsc -w``` (watch mode) will not exit. A better way will be to use ```concurrently```,  like the following  ```"start:build": "tsc -w",
    "start:run": "nodemon build/index.js",
    "start": "concurrently npm:start:*"```

Comment: Depends on how the nodemon restarts the server. I restarted my computer and things started working again. No clue what was going on.